# Using a Sub Procedure to call a random number and display a string to a label

Tags: vba

Im trying to get a random number to generate and take said random number to display a certain line of text assigned to that number to a label through a Sub Procedure.

If this is any easier:

1. Generate Random Number 1 Through 5
2. Call Random Number using Sub Procedure
3. Display a string to a label that is connected to that random number.

I'll show my code just so you guys know what my direction is and if it's correct.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnInsult_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsult.Click
    Dim strInsult As String
    Dim intNumber As Integer
    Randomize()
    intNumber = Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)

End Sub
Sub showInsult()

End Sub

End Class
```

It really isn't much and I *think* I'm moving in the right direction. Please ask me if you need more clarification on things.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar piece of code for generating random messages.
Unlike your code above, this was written inside a form module, not a class one and prints to a text box, not a label. I am not sure whether by

> Display a string to a label

you actually mean changing an actual label caption. If so, then use the `showInsultEx` sub instead. Here it is, adapted to your needs. I hope this helps.

```
Private arrInsults() As Variant
Private nInsultCount As Integer

Private Sub Insult_InitRepertoire()
    'init the insult array
    arrInsults = Array( _
    "Insult 1", _
    "Insult 2", _
    "Insult 3", _
    "Insult 4", _
    "Insult 5")

    nInsultCount = UBound(arrInsults) - LBound(arrInsults) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub showInsult()
    'init the insult array if empty
    If nInsultCount = 0 Then Insult_InitRepertoire

    'get a random entry from the insult table
    'and print it in the text field
    Randomize
    Me.TextBox1.Text = arrInsults(LBound(arrInsults) + Int(Rnd() * nInsultCount))
End Sub

Private Sub btnInsult_Click()
    'invoke the pseudo-random inslut generator
    showInsult
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'prevent user input
    Me.TextBox1.Locked = True
End Sub

Private Sub showInsultEx()
    Dim nId As Integer

    'init the insult array if empty
    If nInsultCount = 0 Then Insult_InitRepertoire

    'get a random entry from the insult table
    'and print it in the text field
    Randomize
    nId = LBound(arrInsults) + Int(Rnd() * nInsultCount)

    'get a control associated with the insult number
    'change its caption to the generated text
    'you'll have to make sure to number the controls
    'according to the array indices
    Me.Controls("Label" & nId).Caption = arrInsults(nId)
End Sub
```